# Can i combine unicode categories in Regex?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, categories

I want to get such set of symbols:

1. `\P{L}` unicode category use as base
2. add `хХxXтТTоОoO0` symbols to `\P{L}` unicode category
3. do not use symbols `-_.`

By that i get such regex in Java:

```
[[\P{L}]&&[^-_.]&&[хХxXтТTоОoO0]]
```

But this not working, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#intersection) using `&&[хХxXтТTоОoO0]` means an intersection.

You could add matching `хХxXтТTоОoO0` to the first character class `[\\P{L}хХxXтТTоОoO0]`

Then use [subtraction](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction) for that character class using `&&[^-_.]`

```
[[\\P{L}хХxXтТTоОoO0]&&[^-_.]]
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/JTLyFR)

Example

```
final String regex = "[[\\P{L}хХxXтТTоОoO0]&&[^-_.]]";
final String string = "aTo-_.#$";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
T
o
#
$
```